# App Store Submission, iPhone vs IPad dimensions

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, app-store

If I specify my app to be an 'iphone' app in XCode, does the app need to be presentable/functional on iPad to any degree ? All of the artwork I've gotten made is iPhone centric, it doesn't really fit the entire iPad screen and looks really bad when run on the iPad simulator.

I would hate to get rejected for this reason, but don't want to have to edit all my art (it's a game) for this alone when my app isn't made for the iPad in the first place.

Does anyone have experience with this ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason my app still looked bad was because my info.plist still specified supported iPad orientations despite marking the application as iPhone only. Once I deleted that entry of the plist, everything scaled properly

Answer (score 0):

If you set your app up as iPhone only, it will run in **a special iPhone mode** when running on an iPad. This means that the application will have the logical dimension of an iPhone 4s (320x480) and will be displayed on the center of the screen. It can be enlarged with the button in the lower-right corner.

[image: Devices option set to iPhone under Deployment Info]

[image: iPhone-only app running on iPad]